# passing scope to directive in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following Angular controller with a simple http get in it:

```
angular.module('SCtrl', ['ng-fusioncharts']).controller('SCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    //Get All errors.
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'node/errors'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.notifications = response.data;
        console.log($scope.notifications);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
}
```

This works fine.

I then have the following directive. I want to be able to put {{notifications}} in the module body, however it doesn't work. I am guessing this is because I give the directive its own scope. What is the correct way to link scopes? My attempt is below but this doesn't work.

Thanks!

```
angular.module('SCtrl').directive('listDirective',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
            listTitle:"@",
            notifications:"="
        },
        templateUrl: '../templates/listWidget.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            $scope.notifications=scope.notifications;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you use the `notifications` directly in your `listWidget.html`, you can just do `<list-directive notifications="notifications"></list-directive>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mis uderstood initially, as @devqon pointed out, you need to pass your `notification` object in `list-directive` which can be accessed in your `listWidget.html`

```
<list-directive notifications="notifications"></list-directive>
```

Comment: Better :) But don't know if complete, because it seems OP wants to have the `notifications` in the link function for whatever (unmentioned) reason

Comment: @devqon: not needed actually, that's where initially i got confused... as the object should be available in the view... unless he wants to do some sort of manipulation again

Comment: Thanks for this... this works but is there a way to do it I don't need to pass it in the html? What's best practice?

Comment: @MattBoyle: typically you would pass the value, if you don't want then you need to remove the scope object completely which would not create an isolate scope.. and access your controller scope directly

Answer (score 0):

```
<list-directive notifications="notifications"></list-directive>

link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.notifications=scope.notifications;
        }
```

You should assign the values notifications="notifications" otherwise you can't get. Or else you can trigger API call in directive itself. Now you don't need to assign notifications="notifications".